# Create a dictionary with length of elements in a list as keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list where there are multiple elements as tuples stored in a list, I want to create a dictionary where the key is length like 1,2 etc and the elements of respective lengths.
The example of list is

```
combination = [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('A', 'B'), ('A','C'),
 ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), 
('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D'),('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]
```

I have tried 
`temp_dict = {len(i): i for i in combinations}`

The desired output is

````
{1: [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)], 2: [('A', 'B'), ('A','C'),
 ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')], 3: [('A', 'B', 'C'), 
('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')], 4: [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]}```
````

Answer (score 6):

You can try a dictionary comprehension with a list comprehension within it

```
temp_dict = {len(i): [x for x in combination if len(x) == len(i)] for i in combination}
print(temp_dict)
```

Or you could use a `setdefault`:

```
temp_dict = {}
for i in combination:
    temp_dict.setdefault(len(i), []).append(i)
print(temp_dict)
```

Both Output:

```
{1: [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)], 2: [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')], 3: [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')], 4: [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]}
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid solution, but very inefficient for large dictionaries, being O(n^2)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added a solution with `setdefault` which may well be more efficient.

Comment: `setdefault` is O(n). The only problem with it is that it creates an empty list even when it isn't needed. This is an insignificant penalty in every way except emotionally :)

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach `{len(i): i for i in combination}` actually picks the last tuple of a specific length and adds it to the dictionary, which is not what you want, instead you want a list of all such tuples.

You can use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create a dict of lists as values. Then you can iterate over the list and append the tuples of the same length to the key

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

#Iterate over the list
for item in combination:
    #Append tuples with same length to same value list
    res[len(item)].append(item)

print(dict(res))
```

The output will be

```
{1: [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)], 
2: [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')], 
3: [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')], 
4: [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `itertools.groupby`. Note that `groupby` assumes your data is *sorted*.

```
from itertools import groupby

{k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(combination, key=len)}
```

Output:

```
{1: [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)],
 2: [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')],
 3: [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')],
 4: [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another shot at it is via `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> dict([(cnt, list(l)) for cnt, l in groupby(combinations, len)])
{1: [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)], 2: [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')], 3: [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')], 4: [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]}
```